# Python - fix Persian text file saved with wrong encoding

Tags: python, encoding, farsi

There are a lot of subtitles in Persian saved with wrong encoding. there are some options in video players to fix & display this files correctly but there is only one windows software which actually fix the file & save it with correct encoding. I want to do this in python. I've tried many things but was unable to get this done. notepad says file is in ANSI so I opened it as 'Latin-1' in python & tried to decode & encode it as UTF-8 but it gives me the original file. file can be downloaded from https://ufile.io/np0rodjg
also, fixed file with mentioned software can be downloaded from https://ufile.io/ignop48m 
how this can be done using python?

Comment: Please don't use some unkown third party file uploader. Use github or pastbin or something similar well known.

Comment: it was my first time trying to upload & include file so I have no idea which uploader I should use. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the file is encoded in cp1256, aka Windows-1256, the code page used for Persian and Urdu in Windows.  To create a UTF-8 version of the file, you'll just need to read it in this code page and write out in UTf-8:

```
with open("source.srt", "rt", encoding="cp1256") as f:
    data = f.read()

with open("fixed.srt", "wt", encoding="utf_8_sig") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: I tried cp1256 not as encoding parameter but in decode() function called on file read as 'rb'. your solution fix the problem thanks!